# The precise meaning of "often" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Old houses are **often** damp.

Does the sentence mean:

> 1. **Many/a lot of** old houses are damp.

or

> 2. **Most of** old houses are damp.

?

Comment: LIke many words in English, or any other language, _often_ does not have a precise meaning. Your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Could you provide a link or some additional context? The word could be referring to the quantity of old houses or the frequency that old houses are damp (as in, it implies all old houses become damp, and they become damp often).

Comment: @Lambie The bilingual dictionary I used for "often" was the reason I asked the question. It gives the sentence as an example of the usage of "often", and translates it with a word that means "most of".

Comment: @Lambie Doesn't "frequently" mean "a lot of/many"?

Answer (score 1):

"Most" is objective (more than 50%). The rest of the terms in your question ("often", "many", "a lot") are pretty subjective. So your first choice is probably the intended meaning.

"Often" (along with "many" and "a lot") just means more frequently than you would expect, not *necessarily* more frequently than 50% (which would be "most").

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the term "often" is subjective.  One person might say it *often* rains in their local city, because it rains once a week, but someone from somewhere it rains daily might call that "infrequent".

Where the intention is ambiguous, it's best to assume to treat this as a general opinion or observation, rather than any specific value.  Without further context, "Old houses are *often* damp," means this a *common* issue with these houses, and something people should keep in mind when choosing to live in one.

A similar example:

> This time of year, we **often** see whales swimming off the coast.

This doesn't mean it happens every year, or some specific value like "more than 50% of the time".  It also doesn't mean that the whales are there but we don't always see them.  It simply describes a common, and regularly occurring phenomenon.

It also suggests that people who visit the area hoping to whale-watch might not see them, otherwise we would say:

> This time of year, we **always** see whales swimming off the coast.

One more example:

> In San Diego it's **often** cold and overcast in May and June.

Actually, it's *almost always* cold and overcast at this time of year, so much so that we have a saying: "May grey; June gloom".  However, while it happens many days of the month, I can't predict the weather.  I have no idea whether this month will be the same as last year, or whether it will definitely be overcast on May 15th.  I'm simply making an observation about a known *trend*.

Answer (score 0):

often means frequently.

**often, never, always, frequently, usually are adverbs.**

An adverb cannot be switched to become a noun.

You can have **most** and **lots of** and **often** in the same sentence.

- Most people in my class are **often** late.
- Lots of people are **often** funny without realizing it.

Often above means how people are.

Google Dictionary
ad·verb
/ˈadˌvərb/
nounGRAMMAR
plural noun: adverbs
**a word or phrase that modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or other adverb or a word** group, expressing a relation of place, time, circumstance, manner, cause, degree, etc. (e.g., gently, quite, then, there ).